# SQL server returning wrong results for a varchar comparison

Tags: sql-server

It's amazing. Everything looks good but SQL Server returns wrong results for a `varchar` comparison.

The below are the commands I passed but I am getting contradictory results for each command.

Sorry for inconvenience. Stack overflow is not allowing me to add images.

```
 select * from book_loans

 select max(loan_no) as max_number from book_loans

 select * from book_loans where loan_no = '12'
```

Here are the tables and results:

```
book_loans (first query result):

loan_no book_id branch_id   card_no date_out    due_date    date_in
1   0399147020  1   9019    2013-11-22  2013-12-06  2013-12-01
10  0192860925  4   9009    2014-04-18  2014-05-02  NULL
11  0805057579  1   9021    2014-04-18  2014-05-02  NULL
12  0911625607  2   9018    2014-04-19  2014-05-03  NULL
2   0030059380  4   9007    2013-12-01  2013-12-15  2013-12-16
3   0671880756  5   9018    2013-12-08  2013-12-22  2013-12-22
4   0911625291  3   9013    2014-01-02  2014-01-16  2014-01-12
5   0688161995  5   9022    2014-02-10  2014-02-24  2014-03-01
6   0911625291  2   9011    2014-03-03  2014-03-17  2014-03-16
7   1861003730  3   9034    2014-04-17  2014-05-01  NULL
8   0201612585  3   9034    2014-04-17  2014-05-01  NULL
9   1565927699  3   9034    2014-04-17  2014-05-01  NULL
```

Second query result:

```
max_number
9
```

Third query result:

```
result is empty
```

Comment: can you tell me the datatype of loan_no??

Comment: sorry forgot to mention. loan_no is a varchar(10)

Comment: execute this query and tell me the result.`select * from book_loans where loan_no=12`

Comment: Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '
1' to data type int.

Comment: I test it,but it is working fine on my pc,i can send you my test project

Comment: that would be really helpfull bro. can you mail it to revanth0212@gmail.com

Comment: 9 is right isn't it? You comparing that field lexicographically?

Comment: but there is 12 right? @almas can you elaborate on lexicographic ally comparing issue

Comment: @RevanthKumar,update me with the status

Comment: what do you expect output of string field like "1", "11", "2"? 1 comes before 2 so field 1 comes before 2, for field 2 i.e. 11 digit in tens place is 1 which comes before 2 hence placed before.

Comment: @almas so what do you think the query should be for returning the max of the loan_no given loan_no is a varchar(10)?

Comment: 2 is clear, lexical, 3 leads to the assumption that your number are stored with leading white spaces. Cast as integer or better change the field type.

Comment: Is it not possible at this time to have Loan_no as Int ?

Comment: SELECT MAX(CAST(loan_no as INT)) from book_loans

Comment: @Revanth: You need to cast it as Integer. Either you are comparing or selecting, you need to cast/convert loan_no field to integer.

Comment: not i cant convert the loan_no to int. It is one of the constraint. 
the query which @almas gave seems good by theory but isnt working in sql server.

Comment: If `loan_no` obviously is a **number** - ***WHY*** isn't it **STORED** as a number? E.g. it should really be a `INT` (or `BIGINT`, or `DECIMAL(p,s)`) datatype - don't just store everything as `varchar` !!

Comment: I think there are **space** on column i.e. **' 1'**, maybe SELECT MAX(CAST(**LTRIM**(**RTRIM**(loan_no)) as INT)) from book_loans. Totally agree with @marc_s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you stored it as `varchar`. There is a possibility of storing `empty space` before the value. So like others said you need to convert to int then do the comparison or aggregation what ever you want.

check this

```
CREATE TABLE #t
  (a VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO #t
VALUES      (' 12')

SELECT *
FROM   #t
WHERE  a = '12'
```

no rows will be returned here.

```
SELECT *
FROM   #t
WHERE  convert(int,a) = '12'
```

Here 1 row will be returned.

So if a field is going to hold a numeric value then it should always be of numeric type (int,bigint,numeric,decial, etc..)